# How to add only one specific item to DropDownList from ViewBag data source?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I am trying to fix a bug in an existing application, and my MVC ViewBag skills are limited.  First off, I don't have the time to refactor and change the code from a ViewBag to a ViewModel, although that would be my preferred approach.

I want to populate a DropDownList from an object in the ViewBag.  The code is here:

```
if(Model != null && Model.WarehouseId != null && !Model.WarehouseId.Equals(String.Empty))                
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WarehouseId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.WarehouseCodes)<br /> //<---
}
else
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.WarehouseId, (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.WarehouseCodes, "")<br /> 
}
```

In the case that the WarehouseID is not String.Empty, I ONLY want to load that value into the DropDownList.  I'm open to a C# or jQuery answer to this question.

Thanks in advance for any help offered!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> and my MVC ViewBag skills are limited

If you forget those skills it would be even better for you. Just kidding, they could be useful in order to know what **not** to do in an ASP.NET MVC application :-)

Anyway:

```
if (Model != null && Model.WarehouseId != null && !Model.WarehouseId.Equals(String.Empty))                
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        m => m.WarehouseId, 
        ((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.WarehouseCodes).Where(x => x.Value == Model.WarehouseId.Value)
    )
    <br />
}
else
{
    @Html.DropDownListFor(
        m => m.WarehouseId, 
        (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.WarehouseCodes, 
        ""
    )
    <br /> 
}
```

Another approach is to handle this case in your controller action:

```
public ActionResult Index()
{
    SomeModel model = ...
    IEnumerable<SelectItem> warehouseCodes = ...
    ViewBag.HasValue = false;
    if (model != null && model.WarehouseId != null && !string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.WarehouseId.Value))
    {
        warehouseCodes = warehouseCodes.Where(x => x.Value == model.WarehouseId.Value);
        ViewBag.HasValue = true;
    }
    ViewBag.WarehouseCodes = warehouseCodes;
    return View(model);
}
```

and in your view you could now replace the `if` with:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(
    m => m.WarehouseId, 
    (IEnumerable<SelectListItem>)ViewBag.WarehouseCodes, 
    ViewBag.HasValue ? (string)null : ""
)
```